# writing a whole list into one row in csv python

Tags: python, list, csv

I have a list and a variable

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
myVariable = 10
```

and I would like to write this list and the variable to a CSV file using Python and it should be written like this (but with tab between adjacent values and without ","):

```
10 a b c d
```

and not like this:

```
10
a
b
c
d
```

So far I have:

```
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
file = open("CSVfile" + '.csv','w', newline='', encoding='utf-8')
writer = csv.writer(file)
writer.writerow(myVariable)
writer.writerow(myList)
```

Comment: You expect calling `writerow` twice will *not* produce 2 rows in the result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<s>First off, try not to name your variables the same as builtin types (list). This can break lots of stuff.</s>
Edit: nvm I saw you edited your post.

You can just merge the list and variable into a string and then write that. You don't even need the csv writer.

```py
myList = [a,b,c,d]
with open("CSVfile" + '.csv','w', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    line = '\t'.join([myVariable] + myList)
    f.write(line + '\n')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the csv module as your question suggests (docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#module-contents)), you can do it this way:

```py
import csv
myList = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
myVariable = 10
with open('CSVfile.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writerow([myVariable] + myList)
```

Note that `delimiter` is specified as '\t' (tab) in the call to `csv.writer()`, and we append the variable and the list to create a new list which is used as an argument to `writerow()`.